# Proper Way to Fetch Latest Addition to Django Model

Tags: ajax, django

I need to fetch latest post, periodically, from my Django model when user is logged on in my site. Of course, with AJAX. Twitter and Facebook do this.

At first load, latest, 20 posts is fetched `posts = Post.objects.all()[:20]` and I store 20 in `request.session['post_fetched']`. My infinite scroll towards the bottom page works fine with code below:

```
post_fetched = request.session['post_fetched']
new_post = Post.objects.all()[post_fetched: post_fetched + 20]
request.session['post_fetched'] += 20
```

I have `100` total posts in `Post.objects.all()` and I want to be a able to check if there is addition to the table and fetch the ones added but I can't wrap my head around how to do it, properly.

Assuming the post increment to 107. The only way, for me, I can be able to fetch the 7 post is to do the following:

```
request.session['total'] = len(Post.objects.all()) #this will be on first page load.
```

And my AJAX to fetch latest posts:

```
total = request.session['total']
lastest_post = Post.objects.all()[total:]
request.session['total'] = len(Post.objects.all())
```

How do I fetch the lastest post without having to always count the total posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this is to record in the session an identifier from the last record to be shown, and then query for those records that are after that. You could use the pk for that, but it would probably be safer to explicitly set a `created_at` datetimefield (using `auto_now_add`). Now you can do:

```
last_fetched = request.session['last_fetched']
new_posts = list(Post.objects.filter(created_at__gt=last_fetched)[:20])
request.session['last_fetched'] = new_posts[19].created_at
```

Comment: This is the time I am using this now on my site. Why `pk` not safer compared to `datetimefield (using `auto_now_add`)?

Comment: Because strictly speaking the pk is an opaque number that has nothing to do with ordering. Although it is unlikely, it could happen that a later post was allocated an earlier pk.